# Import NumPy fails using Windows despite it being installed

Tags: python-3.x, windows, numpy, import

I just managed to get this figured out but i couldn't find a post about my specific problem so here it is.

I had installed numpy using

```
py -m pip install NumPy
```

I got the following error when I tried to import it

```
>>> import NumPy 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NumPy'
```

I solved my problem by unistalling NumPy and re-installing it with all LOWER-CASE LETTERS i.e.

```
py -m pip install numpy
```

Now I can import it with lower case letters

```
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

hope this can help someone else save an hour.

Comment: `pip` is not case sensitive. You were installing `numpy` in both cases. Additionally, NumPy documentation clearly uses `import numpy`.

Comment: Is the import function case sensitive?  Could I have created case sensitive directories by installing it with the name in the wrong case?

Comment: Python as a whole *is* case sensitive. Both installations created the same directories because `pip` is *not* case sensitive.